# Как исправить ошибку: Необработанное исключение по адресу...

Tags: c++

Такое сообщение: **Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00A8AF69 в ConsoleApplication5.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x005BF000.**

Я выполнил трассировку, стрелка указала на восьмую строчку. Бесконечного цикла, как мне кажется, нет. Да и массив создан динамический. В чем ошибка?

```
  { 
  int i, j, k, pos = -1, N, M;
  int *d = new int;//Массив сдвигов
  N = s.length();
  M = find.length();
  clock_t t0 = GetTickCount(); // начальное время
  // Формирование таблицы сдвигов d
  for(i = 0; i <= N; i++)
  d[i] = M;
  for(i = 0; i < M - 1; i++)
  d[find[i]] = M - i - 1;
  // Поиск образца P в тексте S
  i = M;
  do{
  k = i;
  j = M;
    do
{
  j--;
  k--;
}
while(j >= 0 && s[k] == find[j]);
if(j == -1)
  pos = i - M;
else
  i += d[s[i - 1]];
 }
 while(i <= N && j >= 0);
 if(j > -1)
 cout << "Образец найден по смещению pos : " << pos-1 << endl; 
 else 
 cout << "Образец не найден" << endl;
 clock_t t1 = GetTickCount();// конечное время
 cout << "Время поиска : " << (double)(t1 - t0)/1000 << endl;// время поиска
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @Sergos приведите код в порядок

Comment: А что Вы пытались сделать? Что такое "сдвиг" и "образец"? Кстати, программу расхотелось читать уже после первой строчки...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Sergos](/users/32801/sergos), ошибка очевидна -- Вы пишете в память, которая на самом деле не выделена.

Смотрите:

```
 int *d = new int;//Массив сдвигов
```

Тут Вы выделили память под **один** int. Судя по коду

```
 for(i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   d[i] = M;   <---- ошибка????
```

нужен массив из `s.length()` чисел.

Вот и создавайте его правильно:

```
 int *d = new int[s.length()];//Массив сдвигов
```

--

Но в свете следующего фрагмента

```
 for(i = 0; i < M - 1; i++)
   d[find[i]] = M - i - 1;
```

учитывая

```
 M = find.length(); // а что за символы в строке find?
```

вообще-то остаются вопросы  к алгоритму.

Comment:     M = find.length(); // find это переменная типа string
В ней хранится слово введенное для отыска.

Comment:     int *d = new int; // я заменил эту часть кода на эту  
    int *d = new int[s.length()];
Но сообщение об ошибке осталось прежним, зато при трассировке стрелка показала на эту строку:
    while(j >= 0 && s[k] == find[j]);
    if(j == -1)
    pos = i - M;
    else
    i += d[s[i - 1]]; <----- ВОТ эта строка

Comment: >> вообще-то остаются вопросы к алгоритму.

> В ней хранится слово введенное для отыска.

Вон оно как! Это же алгоритм для отыска. Во мы дураки-то, да, avp?

Главное, функции впрыска, соскока и убёга реализовать не забудь!

Comment: VadimTukaev я прямо таки порезался о вашу остроту ума. Желаешь по выкаблучиваться в интернете? Что же, это очень смело, тогда флаг тебе в руки. Если у тебя низкая самооценка, кто же тебе доктор.

Comment: @Sergos, смотрите, в выражении

    d[s[i - 1]]

в качестве индекса массива `d` используется **код символа** из строки `s`. 

Если строка состоит из однобайтных символов (кстати, Вы бы все-таки весь код  относящийся к делу выложили), то значение кода такого символа может быть от -128 до 127 или если перейти к unsigned от 0 до 255.

Поэтому я думаю, что массив `d[]` можно объявить и инициализировать так

     int d[256];
     for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
       d[i] = M;

а при его индексации значениями символов приводить тип символа к unsigned

     d[(unsigned char)s[i - 1]]

Comment: avp, я добавил код относящийся к делу. И сделал как Вы советовали, только объявил массив не так:
 
    int d[256];

а так: 

    int *d = new int[256];
 
и все наладилось, благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Ну и славно.